# Error in HTTP response header

Tags: php, http, nginx, header, http-status-code-301

i have a vps server (using nginx,httpd,and mysql), my domain is somedomain.ac.id, but i have some error in http response, this is my http response

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found => 
Server => nginx admin
Date => Fri, 09 Oct 2015 10:31:51 GMT
Content-Type => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length => 202
Connection => close
Location => https://google.com
X-Cache => HIT from Backend
```

my problem is when i share my url domain to facebook it's always point to google.com
why the "Location" always point to google.com? how to edit "Location" value?
please help

Answer (score 0):

Contact your domain provider, your domain dns is forwarding to google.com

Comment: i have access to vps using putty, how can i edit dns manually? by the way thank you for your response